# How to format this string with new lines?

Tags: php, paypal-ipn

I am using the PayPal IPN to verify and process orders.

The PayPal IPN forwards the details to the php script of the payment & delivery details.

One variable is the first line address, PayPal forwards it like this:

> address_street=Company+Name%0D%0ABuilding+Name%2C+118+Street+Name

I don't quite understand why the new line characters are different here.

If I output this to an HTML email, it displays like this:

> Company Name Building Name 118 Street Name

How can I get this to output to this instead?:

> Company Name
>  
>   Building Name
>   118 Street Name

Comment: `echo nl2br($myAddressDataString);` - PHP docs for [nl2br()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

Comment: Thanks, I assumed this would only work with /n

Comment: `Returns string with '<br />' or '<br>' inserted before all newlines (\r\n, \n\r, \n and \r).` and `%0D` is simply a urlencoded `\r`

Comment: It worked for the first line break, not the second. I will test something else for that

Comment: @MarkBaker If you add an answer I'll mark as correct.

Comment: Well `%2C` isn't a line break (if that's what you mean by the second), it's a comma (`,`), so strictly speaking there should only be two lines in this address

Comment: I'll leave it like that. Will be up to the distribute how they print it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$address_street="Company+Name%0D%0ABuilding+Name%2C+118+Street+Name";

echo str_replace('+'," ",rawurldecode($address_street));

            OR

echo str_replace("+"," ",str_replace('%2C',"</br>" ,str_replace('%0D%0A',"</br>",$address_street)));
```

Comment: I used `nl2br` in the end. I tested with rawurldecode anyway but it didn't make a difference.

Comment: echo str_replace("+"," ",str_replace('%2C',"</br>" ,str_replace('%0D%0A',"</br>",$address_street)));